# Laravel, how to get the variable from js?

Tags: javascript, php

**Views**

```
Deadline: <span class = "deadline">this will replace a new date</span>
```

**JS**

```
$.each(items, function (index, value) {
        talent = new TalentListMasonry({
          deadline: value.timeline,
          url: value.talent_url,
          isUrgent: value.is_urgent == 1
        });
        var final = talent.make();
        lll.append(final).isotope('insert', final);
      });
```

My question is, how do i check the date is equal to 2017-12-30?

my idea is like this,

```
@if(deadline == 2017-12-30)
  <h1>Success</h1>
@endif
```

Comment: You need call ajax to pass it server side language.

Comment: any idea how do i do that? i tried to find the solution but everything is only explaining the theory about client and server side but not the codes